# SpringBoot Devtools without IDE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I was wondering whether is possible to use the devtools within spring-boot and Maven only, without any IDE. 
My question is about quick changes tests, using sublime text or notepad++ and console `mvn spring-boot:run`.

As I know, It could be done using `mvn compile` in another console. But, I was thinking something simpler such as `ng serve` does in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I found two plugins for sublime and one for notepad++ which execute console command (in your case `mvn compile`) on save event.

[SublimeCommandOnSave](https://github.com/klaascuvelier/SublimeCommandOnSave) - this plugin is directly dedicated to run command on save event.
[sublime-hooks](https://github.com/twolfson/sublime-hooks) - this one has a lot of more option than previous, you can fire diffrent actions (i.e console command, http request) on diffrent events.

In notepad++ case please refer [this](https://superuser.com/questions/390805/in-notepad-how-can-i-execute-a-script-like-using-f5-but-with-every-save-ctr) question.